# first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, concertHTMLToLongText: execution of BeforeUpdate

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, before-trigger, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to update the Knowledge article through data loader. We have a trigger on the Update (before update event) of the  Knowledge articles. The trigger calls a apex class is like below

```
trigger concertHTMLToLongText on Knowledge__kav(before update) {
    publishUnPublishArticles psh = new publishUnPublishArticles();
    for (Knowledge__kav con : Trigger.New) {
        String unPubknow_ArticleId = psh.unPublishArticle(con.KnowledgeArticleId);
        String updateKnow_ArticleId = psh.updateDraftArticleWithoutPublish(unPubknow_ArticleId);
        psh.publishArticle(updateKnow_ArticleId);
    }    
}
```

And the publishUnPublishArticles  class is like

```
public with sharing class publishUnPublishArticles {
    
    public  void publishArticle(String recordId) { //It need to be KnowledgeArticleId
        KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(recordId, true);
    }

    public  String unPublishArticle(String recordId){ //It need to be KnowledgeArticleId
        String newArticleId = KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle(recordId, true); 
        return [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id =: newArticleId].KnowledgeArticleId;   
    }
    
    public  String updateDraftArticleWithoutPublish(Id recordId) {
        Knowledge__kav con = [ SELECT Id, Legacy_Solution__c,KnowledgeArticleId, Article_Body_Long_T__c,SOP_Article_Body__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE KnowledgeArticleId =: recordId ];   
        
        Solution result = [SELECT SolutionNote FROM Solution WHERE Id =: con.Legacy_Solution__c];
        
        if (result != null) {
            con.Article_Body_Long_T__c = result.SolutionNote;
            String rep = con.Article_Body_Long_T__c.replaceAll('<|>', '');
            con.SOP_Article_Body__c = rep.replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');
        }
        update con;
        return con.KnowledgeArticleId;
   }}
```

And when I update the record through the data loader I get the error like

`concertHTMLToLongText: execution of BeforeUpdate`

`caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, concertHTMLToLongText: execution of BeforeUpdate`

`caused by: System.HandledException: You can't perform this action. Be sure the action is valid for the current state of the article, and that you have permission to perform it.`

`Class.KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle: line 37, column 1`
`Class.publishUnPublishArticles.unPublishArticle: line 9, column 1`
`Trigger.concertHTMLToLongText: line 22, column 1: []`

`Class.publishUnPublishArticles.updateDraftArticleWithoutPublish: line 29, column 1 Trigger.concertHTMLToLongText: line 23, column 1`

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing here. I tried to execute the Apex Class separately through the Execute in Annonymous Window by passing the KnowledgeArticleId and it works without any issues.

***** Edit *** I tried to tweak a little now I see a different error. I added a check Recursion class to make sure the trigger is running only once like below

```
trigger concertHTMLToLongText on Knowledge__kav(before update) {
     if(checkRecursion.runOnce()){
    publishUnPublishArticles psh = new publishUnPublishArticles();
    for (Knowledge__kav con : Trigger.New) {
        String unPubknow_ArticleId = psh.unPublishArticle(con.Id);
        String updateKnow_ArticleId = psh.updateDraftArticleWithoutPublish(unPubknow_ArticleId);
        psh.publishArticle(updateKnow_ArticleId);
    }    }
}
```

CheckRecursion is

```
public Class checkRecursion{

        private static boolean run = true;
        public static boolean runOnce(){
          if(run){
           run=false;
           return true;
          }else{
            return run;
          }
        }
    }
```

Now I get the error `Only draft articles can be updated: Publication Status`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110423/discussion-on-question-by-user81642-first-error-cannot-insert-update-activate-e).